# After fitting a linear function to a set of data, how can I find the error on the gradient of the function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I currently fit a linear function to distance vs. time graph in order to work out the velocity of a particle...

```
velocity, intercept = numpy.polyfit(time, displacement, 1)
```

How can I then find an estimate of the error in this velocity measurement?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

coefficients = numpy.polyfit(time, displacement, 1)
fitted_data = np.poly1d(coefficients)

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(fitted_data, displacement)
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. In the docs it says 'Standard error of the estimate'. Does this mean the standard error of the gradient or intercept?

Comment: Sorry, garbled code my end. It's the standard error of the entire fit, so the error in both (`displacement = gradient * time + intercept`) as displacement is a function of both.

Answer (score 0):

**Are your time-values placed equidistantly? If yes,** you could simply interpolate the velocities by

```
velocitiy_between = (displacement[1:]-displacement[:-1])/(time[1:]-time[:-1])
```

these velocities now are defined not on, but in between your data points. You then can assign to each data point the average of it's left and right approximation by

```
velocity = (velocity_between[1:]+velocity_between[:-1])/2.0
```

By this you obtain an array of velocities for all inner data points which you can compare to the outcome of your fit.

**If your time-values are not placed equidistantly, you can still** use this approach. But you must assign additional weighting factors to your errors depending on the data density, to consider the fact that slopes between nearby points are better approximated. Also the averaging between the neighbors becomes dependent on the distance to the neighbors.

Just leave a comment if you need more details for that second case.